# Jmeter: org.apache.jmeter.report.core.SampleException: Could not locate input sample files

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing, jmeter-5.0

I'm trying to run jmeter load testing scripts using CLI using the following command:

**jmeter -n -t {PATH TO JMETER SCRIPT(JMX)} -l {PATH TO JTL FILE} -e -o {PATH OF FOLDER WHERE YOU WISH TO SAVE REPORT DASHBOARD}**

**Example:**

**H:\Apache Jmeter 5.0\bin>jmeter -n -t C:\stressTest\Master-Script.jmx -l C:\stressTest\Results\Result-${currentTime}.csv -e -o C:\stressTest\Html\${currentTime}**

and the scripts runs and generates the csv file as expected, but while generating the html report (web reports dashboard), I get the following output:

```
Starting the test @ Tue Mar 03 13:01:30 EST 2020 (1583258490364)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Tue Mar 03 13:01:36 EST 2020 (1583258496832)
Error generating the report: org.apache.jmeter.report.core.SampleException: Could not locate input sample files !
... end of run
```

I'm fairly new and I might be missing something here. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/29584/how-to-create-folder-with-unique-name-while-running-a-jmeter-command-in-non-gui

Answer (score 0):

Neither [cmd.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) is not able resolve your `${currentTime}` expression, if you want to generate a .jtl result file with the timestamp you need to use [date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/date) command like:

```
H:\Apache Jmeter 5.0\bin>jmeter -n -t C:\stressTest\Master-Script.jmx -l C:\stressTest\Results\Result-%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%.csv -e -o C:\stressTest\Html\%date:~10,4%_%date:~4,2%_%date:~7,2%
```

[image]

More information: [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After looking at you answer, I have two questions. 
But first, Let me clarify that running "\Result-${currentTime}" is a variable which I have created in my test script using:

`Name: currentTime Value: ${__time(dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss)}`

Q1. When I run the following command, csv report is getting generated but not the HTML.
`jmeter -n -t C:\stressTest\Master-Script.jmx -l C:\stressTest\Results\Result-${currentTime}.csv -e -o C:\stressTest\Html\${currentTime}`

Q2. When I ran you command, it generates both report and html dashboard.

Also, there is diff b/w reports